Faster way to implement sapply()
I want to use sapply() to conduct some basic calculations:

Calculate the number of times that a value appears in a bootstrap sample

N <- 10000
idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
sapply(1:N, function(j) {sum(idx == j)})


Calculate the sum of one vector corresponding to the index from a bootstrap sample

N <- 10000
idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
vec <- rnorm(1:N) 
sapply(1:nc, function(j) {sum(vec[idx == j])})

However, these are very slow when I put them within loop (I don't know why). For example:
B <- 100
N <- 10000
for (b in 1:B) {
  idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
  vec <- rnorm(1:N) 
  tmp <- sapply(1:N, function(j) {sum(vec[idx == j])})
}

I would like to ask if there is any way to make this faster?


help("table") 2) Isn't that just the counts from 1 times the correponding values in vec? That doesn't need a loop.


for(b in 1:B) is doing nothing. What is nc?

Check collapse::fsum

Here are options for your first and second code blocks, respectively
tabulate(idx, nbins = N)

and
tapply(vec, factor(idx, levels = 1:N), sum, default = 0L)


Instead of using sapply to count occurrences you can use the rowsum.
B <- 100
N <- 10000

results <- vector("list", B)

for (b in 1:B) {
  idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
  vec <- rnorm(N)
  counts <- tabulate(idx, nbins = N)
  sums <- rowsum(vec, group = idx)
  results[[b]] <- list(counts = counts, sums = sums)
}

counts_first <- results[[1]]$counts
sums_first <- results[[1]]$sums


When you want to speed things up, oftentimes Rcpp is helpful.
Consider the following Rcpp solution:
cpp_code <- '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> count_idx(const std::vector<int>& x) {
    std::vector<int> counts(x.size(), 0);
    for (auto& i : x) {
        counts[i - 1]++;
    }
    return counts;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> sum_by_index(const std::vector<double>& vals,
                              const std::vector<int>& idx) {
    std::vector<double> sums(idx.size(), 0);
    for (auto& i : idx) {
        sums[i - 1] += vals[i - 1];
    }
    return sums;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame fun_3_cpp(int N, int B) {
  const int ret_size = N * B;
  std::vector<int> index(ret_size), counts;
  std::vector<double> sums;

  for (int b = 0; b < B; b++) {
    // fill index with the block number
    std::fill_n(index.begin() + b * N, N, b + 1);
    
    // create N random indices
    std::vector<int> idx = as<std::vector<int>>(sample(N, N, true));

    // calculate counts
    std::vector<int> this_counts = count_idx(idx);
    counts.insert(counts.end(), this_counts.begin(), this_counts.end());

    // calculate sums
    // create N random values
    std::vector<double> vals = as<std::vector<double>>(rnorm(N));
    // sum the values by the index
    std::vector<double> this_sum = sum_by_index(vals, idx);
    sums.insert(sums.end(), this_sum.begin(), this_sum.end());
  }

  DataFrame results = DataFrame::create(
    Named("index") = index,
    Named("counts") = counts,
    Named("sums") = sums
  );
  return results;
}
'
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = cpp_code)
# count_idx(c(1L, 1L, 2L))
# expects: 2, 1, 0
# sum_by_index(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), c(1L, 1L, 3L))
# expects: 0.2, 0.2, 0.3

# small wrapper for the Cpp code
fun_3 <- function(N, B) {
  set.seed(123)
  fun_3_cpp(N, B)
}
fun_3(10, 2)
#>    index counts       sums
#> 1      1      1  1.7150650
#> 2      1      0  0.0000000
#> 3      1      1 -1.2650612
#> 4      1      0  0.0000000
#> 5      1      2 -0.8913239
#> 6      1      2  2.4481636
#> 7      1      0  0.0000000
#> 8      1      1  0.4007715
#> 9      1      2  0.2213654
#> 10     1      1 -0.5558411
#> 11     2      1 -1.0678237
#> 12     2      0  0.0000000
#> 13     2      2 -2.0520089
#> 14     2      1 -0.7288912
#> 15     2      1 -0.6250393
#> 16     2      0  0.0000000
#> 17     2      1  0.8377870
#> 18     2      2  0.3067462
#> 19     2      0  0.0000000
#> 20     2      2  2.5076298

Benchmark
Also, when speed is the key metric, always benchmark...
# wut original questions
fun_1 <- function(N, B) {
  set.seed(123)
  results <- list()
  for (b in 1:B) {
    idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
    vec <- rnorm(1:N)
    counts <- sapply(1:N, function(j) {sum(idx == j)})
    sums <- sapply(1:N, function(j) {sum(vec[idx == j])})
    
    results[[b]] <- data.frame(counts = counts, sums = sums)
  }
  return(results)
}
fun_1(10, 2)
#> [[1]]
#>    counts       sums
#> 1       0  0.0000000
#> 2       1  0.5038124
#> 3       2 -0.4467158
#> 4       1  0.2382129
#> 5       1  0.5490967
#> 6       2  1.4794434
#> 7       0  0.0000000
#> 8       0  0.0000000
#> 9       1  1.2947633
#> 10      2  2.5157242
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    counts       sums
#> 1       1  0.8377870
#> 2       0  0.0000000
#> 3       0  0.0000000
#> 4       0  0.0000000
#> 5       2 -0.4494967
#> 6       0  0.0000000
#> 7       3  1.4014184
#> 8       0  0.0000000
#> 9       2  0.6000542
#> 10      2  2.1319484


# Serge's answer;
fun_2 <- function(N, B) {
  set.seed(123)
  results <- vector("list", B)
  
  for (b in 1:B) {
    idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
    vec <- rnorm(N)
    counts <- tabulate(idx, nbins = N)
    sums <- rowsum(vec, group = idx)
    results[[b]] <- list(counts = counts, sums = sums)
  }
  return(results)
}
fun_2(10, 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$counts
#>  [1] 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 1 2
#> 
#> [[1]]$sums
#>          [,1]
#> 2   0.5038124
#> 3  -0.4467158
#> 4   0.2382129
#> 5   0.5490967
#> 6   1.4794434
#> 9   1.2947633
#> 10  2.5157242
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$counts
#>  [1] 1 0 0 0 2 0 3 0 2 2
#> 
#> [[2]]$sums
#>          [,1]
#> 1   0.8377870
#> 5  -0.4494967
#> 7   1.4014184
#> 9   0.6000542
#> 10  2.1319484



# Rcpp version
cpp_code <- '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> count_idx(const std::vector<int>& x) {
    std::vector<int> counts(x.size(), 0);
    for (auto& i : x) {
        counts[i - 1]++;
    }
    return counts;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> sum_by_index(const std::vector<double>& vals,
                              const std::vector<int>& idx) {
    std::vector<double> sums(idx.size(), 0);
    for (auto& i : idx) {
        sums[i - 1] += vals[i - 1];
    }
    return sums;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame fun_3_cpp(int N, int B) {
  const int ret_size = N * B;
  std::vector<int> index(ret_size), counts;
  std::vector<double> sums;

  for (int b = 0; b < B; b++) {
    // fill index with the block number
    std::fill_n(index.begin() + b * N, N, b + 1);
    
    // create N random indices
    std::vector<int> idx = as<std::vector<int>>(sample(N, N, true));

    // calculate counts
    std::vector<int> this_counts = count_idx(idx);
    counts.insert(counts.end(), this_counts.begin(), this_counts.end());

    // calculate sums
    // create N random values
    std::vector<double> vals = as<std::vector<double>>(rnorm(N));
    // sum the values by the index
    std::vector<double> this_sum = sum_by_index(vals, idx);
    sums.insert(sums.end(), this_sum.begin(), this_sum.end());
  }

  DataFrame results = DataFrame::create(
    Named("index") = index,
    Named("counts") = counts,
    Named("sums") = sums
  );
  return results;
}
'
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = cpp_code)
# count_idx(c(1L, 1L, 2L))
# expects: 2, 1, 0
# sum_by_index(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), c(1L, 1L, 3L))
# expects: 0.2, 0.2, 0.3

# small wrapper for the Cpp code
fun_3 <- function(N, B) {
  set.seed(123)
  fun_3_cpp(N, B)
}
fun_3(10, 2)
#>    index counts       sums
#> 1      1      1  1.7150650
#> 2      1      0  0.0000000
#> 3      1      1 -1.2650612
#> 4      1      0  0.0000000
#> 5      1      2 -0.8913239
#> 6      1      2  2.4481636
#> 7      1      0  0.0000000
#> 8      1      1  0.4007715
#> 9      1      2  0.2213654
#> 10     1      1 -0.5558411
#> 11     2      1 -1.0678237
#> 12     2      0  0.0000000
#> 13     2      2 -2.0520089
#> 14     2      1 -0.7288912
#> 15     2      1 -0.6250393
#> 16     2      0  0.0000000
#> 17     2      1  0.8377870
#> 18     2      2  0.3067462
#> 19     2      0  0.0000000
#> 20     2      2  2.5076298



fun_4 <- function(N, B) {
  set.seed(123)
  
  lapply(seq(B), function(b) {
    idx <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
    vec <- rnorm(N)
    
    
    data.frame(counts = tabulate(idx, nbins = N),
               sums = tapply(vec, factor(idx, levels = 1:N), sum, default = 0L))
  })
}
fun_4(10, 2)
#> [[1]]
#>    counts       sums
#> 1       0  0.0000000
#> 2       1  0.5038124
#> 3       2 -0.4467158
#> 4       1  0.2382129
#> 5       1  0.5490967
#> 6       2  1.4794434
#> 7       0  0.0000000
#> 8       0  0.0000000
#> 9       1  1.2947633
#> 10      2  2.5157242
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    counts       sums
#> 1       1  0.8377870
#> 2       0  0.0000000
#> 3       0  0.0000000
#> 4       0  0.0000000
#> 5       2 -0.4494967
#> 6       0  0.0000000
#> 7       3  1.4014184
#> 8       0  0.0000000
#> 9       2  0.6000542
#> 10      2  2.1319484


N <- 1000
B <- 100
bench::mark(
  fun_1(N, B),
  fun_2(N, B),
  fun_3(N, B),
  fun_4(N, B),
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 fun_1(N, B)    1.02s    1.02s     0.981    1.14GB    10.8 
#> 2 fun_2(N, B)  23.28ms  23.49ms    41.5      5.99MB     1.98
#> 3 fun_3(N, B)   5.84ms   5.97ms   159.        2.7MB     3.99
#> 4 fun_4(N, B) 173.43ms 173.74ms     5.68    24.64MB     1.89

Created on 2024-05-31 with reprex v2.1.0
with a clear Rcpp winner!
Out of curiosity, I reran the Rcpp code with the initial N of 10000 and got an median time of 69ms.
